# Getting status = false

Tags: ethers.js, dapps, react

I need a help. I used this [source code](https://github.com/syedmuhamaddanish/Decentralized-Voting-Application-on-Ethereum-Blockchain) to develop a project and its a voting app but i am stuck on this problem

```
async function getCurrentStatus() {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const contractInstance = new ethers.Contract (
        contractAddress, contractAbi, signer
      );
      const status = await contractInstance.getVotingStatus();
      console.log(status);
      setVotingStatus(status);
  }
```

i am getting `status = false` here and its skipping the voting page
but when i change it to  `setVotingStatus(true);`
i am getting the voting page but the remaining time is not working